# WatchOS app keeps crashing when being opened from remote notification

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications, watchkit

WatchOS app works normally if being opened from home screen. If I try to open it from remote notification screen (by tapping title label) two app behaviors can be spotted:

1. If application was loaded previously (I don't know how to name it, maybe better to tell that app is not killed by system or still present in memory). In this case application will load normally and do some action if asked (for example open some Interface Controller and show remote notification details).
2. If application was launched long time ago (or killed by system, unloaded from memory, in my case I'm stopping it in Xcode). If app receives remote notification in this state after tapping on title label of notification scene it will try to load for some time and finally crash (this may take 1sec or 1min). Or it will stuck with loading indicator shown - what is interesting that in this case if I'll try to attach watch extension process to Xcode debug it will show that app is launched and works (for example I can send some data from parent iOS app and watchOS app will receive it - triggered method in Extension delegate and do some stuff).

Googling I have found that watch apps can be killed by system if they take to much power when being launched, so I tried to remove any load while app is starting itself but with no success - it still keeps crashing. 
The only close to mine situation that I've found so far was a topic in apple developers forum:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20553

I have been spotting the same logs like in topic when watching how watch app behave in Xcode/Devices, but after updating to WatchOS 3 (now 3.1 beta) and using new Xcode 8 (now 8.1 beta) I can't see any logs from WatchOS at all (just some system messages that watch screen was turned of and on).

Have any one spotted such issues while working with watchOS remote notifications? Any suggestion where to search for solution?